# auto submit form in drupal

Tags: php, javascript, html, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using drupal.

I have a form which has a single field, the field value increments 1 everytime the form is submitted. The form has a time until it expires, the time is resest every time the form is submitted

Im trying to build a module which will do more, but for a starting point I'm looking at getting the form to auto submit.

The form can be submitted by a random user, and will be with in 1-10 seconds of the form closing.

if anybody can give me anything at all to work with i'd be very greatful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use javascript (I've used jQuery as it's included with Drupal):

```
drupal_add_js("
  (function($) {
    window.setTimout(function(){ $('#my-form-id').submit(); }, 5000)
  })(jQuery);
", 'inline');
```

Just change the `5000` to the number of milliseconds you want until the form auto-submits.

Comment: hi, thank you for answering. Do you know how to get a random authenticated user?

Comment: @SamHealey I would suggest opening a new question for the random authenticated user.

Comment: @SamHealey: I'd agree with brenjt to ask a new question, make sure you mention what version of Drupal you're using as it makes a difference to the DB query method

Comment: the form appears on certain node types, how can I put the nid in this?

Comment: Totally depends, are you attaching the form in `hook_node_view` or `hook_nodeapi` or similar?